# wagmi v2 smart contract interaction

Tags: javascript, ethereum, wagmi

I'm using Rainbowkit latest, alongside wagmi hooks v2.5.7, couldn't find an obvious problem, but I couldn't interact with my smart contract either
basically, the error I'm receiving is that write is not a function
any help is much appreciated, thank you

```
    import React, { useState } from "react"
    import { useAccount, useContractWrite } from "wagmi"
    import { Button, Input, Text } from "@nextui-org/react"
    import {
      presaleAdr as contractAddress,
      presale_ABI as contractABI,
    } from "@/constants/presaleAdr"

    function ModifyRate() {
      const [newRate, setNewRate] = useState("")
      const [error, setError] = useState("")
      const { address, isConnected } = useAccount()

      const {
        write,
        isLoading,
        error: writeError,
      } = useContractWrite({
        addressOrName: contractAddress,
        contractInterface: contractABI,
        functionName: "adjustRates",
        args: [newRate ? BigInt(newRate) : 0],
        onSettled(data, error) {
          if (error) {
            console.error("Transaction Error:", error)
            setError(error.message || "Adjustment failed.")
          } else {
            console.log("Transaction Success:", data)
            setError("")
          }
        },
      })

      const handleAdjustRates = async () => {
        setError("") 
        if (!isConnected) {
          setError("Please connect your wallet first.")
          return
        }

        if (!newRate) {
          setError("Please enter a new rate.")
          return
        }

        try {
          const tx = await write()
          console.log("Transaction initiated:", tx)
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Adjustment failed:", err)
          setError(err.message || "An unexpected error occurred.")
        }
      }

      return (
        <div className="w-1/2 m-auto h-auto">
          <Input
            clearable
            bordered
            fullWidth
            color="primary"
            size="lg"
            placeholder="Enter the new rate"
            value={newRate}
            onChange={(e) => setNewRate(e.target.value)}
            disabled={isLoading}
          />
          <Button
            auto
            disabled={isLoading || !newRate || !isConnected}
            onClick={handleAdjustRates}
          >
            {isLoading ? "Processing..." : "Adjust Rate"}
          </Button>
          {writeError && <Text color="error">{writeError.message}</Text>}
        </div>
      )
    }

    export default ModifyRate



`    function ModifyRate() {
      const [newRate, setNewRate] = useState("")
      const [error, setError] = useState("")
      const { address, isConnected } = useAccount()

      const {
        write,
        isLoading,
        error: writeError,
      } = useContractWrite({
        addressOrName: contractAddress,
        contractInterface: contractABI,
        functionName: "adjustRates",
        args: [newRate ? BigInt(newRate) : 0],
        onSettled(data, error) {
          if (error) {
            console.error("Transaction Error:", error)
            setError(error.message || "Adjustment failed.")
          } else {
            console.log("Transaction Success:", data)
            setError("")
          }
        },
      })

      const handleAdjustRates = async () => {
        setError("") 
        if (!isConnected) {
          setError("Please connect your wallet first.")
          return
        }

        if (!newRate) {
          setError("Please enter a new rate.")
          return
        }

        try {
          const tx = await write()
          console.log("Transaction initiated:", tx)
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Adjustment failed:", err)
          setError(err.message || "An unexpected error occurred.")
        }
      }`
```

`
mainly this is the problem, I used the old useSginer etc, now it's just nonfunctional and wagmi's migration guide is sooo baaad

Comment: I ended up downgrading , and using ethers.js row
    "viem": "^1.21.4",
    "wagmi": "^1.4.13"
    "@rainbow-me/rainbowkit": "^1.3.6",